# Android TV portrait WebView

Tags: webview, orientation, android-tv

I am writing an application that runs on Android TV 5.1 or newer that uses the WebView as the display rendering engine.  I am able to set the desired display orientation, but the WebView rotates back to landscape within the display and maintains the correct aspect ratio.

I have tried using CSS to perform a transform but the aspect ratio is not correct.  I have not found a method to force the WebView to rotate and fit the parent window.

Is there any method to set the orientation and size of the WebView itself?  I see the same behavior on multiple devices.

Comment: The code works correctly in the Android TV emulator, but not on my NVIDIA Shield pro.  I am going to test on other devices I have available.  This may be a behavior of the Shield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is device specific.  Some of the devices I have tested rotate as expected, another device rotates the display, but the WebView rotates back into landscape.  The remaining devices I have tested do not rotate at all.

I will make this will be a known limitation of running this application on Android TV devices.